# The Time Picker Dialog's am and pm buttons are not aligned properly

Tags: android, android-layout, timepicker

The am and pm buttons in my Time Picker Dialog are not aligned properly. This issue has been bugging me for a while but I am unable to fix it. I tried to insert a time picker widget in my layout instead of using the dialog. But it still has that misalignment bug. My code does not modify the time picker in anyway. I only have a code to take in the inputs and set them inside a textView and nothing more.

This problem does not occur for Android versions below 6.0. Also there seems to be no problem with my mobile as the time picker dialog in other apps works fine and doesn't have this misaligned button problem. It seems like only my app has it.

This is the code inside the listener of the dialog.

```
TextView set_text = findViewbyId(R.id.TimeSetText);

set_text.setText(hour+":"+minutes);
```

There is no fault in the rendering of the dialog and the logs don't show any error messages.
[This is the image of Time Picker Dialog with misaligned am and pm buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9yqy.png)

Comment: I have not mentioned this above but I have tried many different ways, which I assumed would fix this problem. But no such luck. I tried to make a different layout file containing the time picker and added the view to an alert dialog. Yes, it did render the time picker just fine but the bug was there. I not longer have any ideas to fix this.

Comment: Found out why it happens. The base theme for the activity is MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar, this creates the issue for me. But I need this theme to render the TextInputLayout properly. Is there a way around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I didn't notice that time picker has a constructor, which takes a theme to set for the dialog. I noticed it when I was typing the code again in the hopes of solving this problem. So then I created a new style with parent ***Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog*** with some colors and button styles for customization and it worked.

I no longer have this issue. I guess this issue occurred because my theme for the activity was *Material No Action Bar*. I don't feel that this was intended though.